# Recursively appending to vector in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, recursion

I'm working on an assignment where the number of eigenvalues of a tridiagonal symmetrical matrix located in the interval [a,b) have to be found. I need to use a bisection algorithm to find these eigenvalues and they have to be outputted in the form of a vector E. The function is function [ E ] = bisection(A, a, b, tol) with tol being the accepted error margin.

```
% If tolerance is met, add (a + b)/2 to E as many times as there are
% eigenvalues left in [a,b). This is the recursive stopping criterium.
if(b - a < tol)
    for i = 1:n
        E = [E; (a + b)/2];
    end
end

% If there are eigenvalues left in [a,b), add new eigenvalues to E through
% recursion.
if(n > 0)
    E = [E; bisection(A, a, (a+b)/2, tol); bisection(A, (a+b)/2, b, tol)];
end

E = [];
```

What I'm trying to do is expanding the vector E with another function call of bisection. Only I get this error:

```
??? Undefined function or variable "E".

Error in ==> bisection at 56
    E = [E; bisection(A, a, (a+b)/2, tol); bisection(A, (a+b)/2, b, tol)];
```

I already made an empty vector E, which I obviously can't put inside the function. So is there any way to expand a vector recursively?

Comment: You are trying to collect an unknown E with the results. Try with initializing E with zeros or NaNs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you cannot put your empty starting vector in the function, you should pass it as an input argument.

This is what the top level code could look like for example:

```
E = [];
E = myRecursiveFunction(E,inputs,stoppingCriteria)
```

Comment: Thank you. I assumed Matlab would use that variable even if it wasn't passed along as an argument.